# Changing the content of the group that I have created

Tags: groups

How do I change the content of the group i have created?  The group that I have exists now is not what I intended to create but I am having difficulty changing it.

Comment: Can you explain better what you mean by "the content of the group"? It would help if you would provide a link to an example on the demo sites.

Answer (score 1):

To start with take a look at the user guide: [Managing Groups](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/organising-your-data/groups-and-tags/#managing-groups)

If that doesn't help, perhaps you could edit your question to provide a bit more information (and a screenshot if possible).